# Sucky armor for long side quest line?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the deal with orange items without stats?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44156/whats-the-deal-with-orange-items-without-stats)
>   [Are there any inherent stats on orange gear?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44212/are-there-any-inherent-stats-on-orange-gear)

Is there something special to do with the armor you get at the end of the Gree(Republic)/Revanites(Empire) quest line?

For a quest level 17, it gives you an orange armor with 25-30 armor. Those who play Swtor know that for that level, it's pretty much sucky as hell.

So does this armor have some special ability I should be aware of, of some utility? Or is it just a massive troll from the Swtor team?

Comment: The quest line also awards you a title ("Soandso, Black Bisector" for Republic).

Comment: @Ingmar +1 by far the best title I've seen ingame yet, I loves me my Black Bisector title. The text in that quest-line is hilarious (or is that obtuse purple?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can upgrade the armor by using commendations (or the GTC auction house) to purchase mods to fill the Armoring, Mod and Enhancement slots. Once you do, you'll see a BIG improvement.

Comment: But couldn't that be said about _any_ armor you're likely to find?

Comment: @JeffMercado No. Orange items have base stats and rely entirely upon the modifiers to give them stats - in essence, they are a shell with a look. Orange items are meant to be useful for as long as you want them, you just need to upgrade the mods. To upgrade the base stats of an orange armor piece, upgrade its Armoring slot.

Comment: @Krazer Further details about orange items have come out. They do have inherit stats... but not exactly. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/45457/1134 for the confusing details.