# Do all orange (upgradeable) items have the same base stats?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the deal with orange items without stats?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44156/whats-the-deal-with-orange-items-without-stats)
>   [Are there any inherent stats on orange gear?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44212/are-there-any-inherent-stats-on-orange-gear)

I've gotten a couple of orange armor pieces and weapons, and it seems like the only thing that varies between them is the look and the upgrades they happen to come with.  Are they all really the same, or are higher level ones better somehow?

Comment: I think someone asked this very question just two days ago or so. Can't find it now, though. The answer is yes, by the way. The mods determine that stats, nothing else. It's super useful for robes, since most of them are ugly, so you can keep the pretty ones and keep changing the mods.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45133/sucky-armor-for-long-side-quest-line is the Q you're thinking, mebbe?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44160/1134

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All orange items, stripped of mods, lack stats of any kind. This gives players the option to keep a piece they really like the look of, and simply upgrade the mods, armor, and enhancements, to keep pace with those who swap out pants like hotcakes.

Even for weapons, base damage is based on the hilt / barrel involved, and is thus fully scalable.