# Why does all the Basic Commendation Gear from Vendors have no Defense?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I am a Level 55 Juggernaut Tank and was looking at the appropriate Vendor for my class and specialization. I had to find out, that the Gear from those Vendors have 0 Defense on it, except 1 Belt and 1 Wrist Item.

Is there any logical explanation for that? Where can I get Gear of the same quality with my Basic Comms but with Defense and more appropriate Tank Stats?

Comment: Let me guess... [the items in question are orange?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44156/whats-the-deal-with-orange-items-without-stats) (Which is to say, I suspect this is a dupe but haven't played SWTOR in long enough to close it without confirming that suspicion...)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz No, they are purple and sold by the ingame vendor for Basic Gear on the Imperial Fleet as well as Oricron. They sell both the same and each class got their own vendor. They have stats, but no Defense. Only Absorb. And even as 450 Artificer, I am unable to make any Enhancements of the same quality that is found in those items. If it is still unclear, then I can make screenshots tomorrow as I am on my way to bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, for-comm tanking gear in SWTOR is optimized incredibly poorly.  With a full set you should be able to manage SM Ops or HM FPs and start getting set bonus pieces with better mods.  As a Guardian/Juggernaut you'll want all Defense augments anyways so you can load up on those on your own (see [this guide](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=616779) for optimal stat distributions).  There are also competitive 54 implants and earpieces on the GTN for cheap with better mitigation than Underworld (rating 168) pieces.

Answer (score 2):

At the Basic Gear Vendor(Lord Galall) there is Black Market Bulwark's MK-1 Gear.

About the stats. It doesn't really matter that much with black Market gear which defensive stats you are using. This matters more in higher Operations.

If you really want "defense" you can buy gear from other basic gear vendor en pull out the enhancements and/or mods.

Comment: BUt I cannot go on higher operations without proper Defense and other Stats. I need 22% Defense, right now I have 13%. I dropped from 18% to 13% when I have dinged to 55. That is not really acceptable.

Comment: You can obtain new gear(66) with the oricon missions. And in combination with Black Market it'll be more than enough to do HM flashpoint and SM Operations. When you start doing these you can think about tweaking your gear. At this point it doesn't really mather to. because you will get better gear really fast.

Comment: Oricon is not really a good source so far. All you get is canisters with random gear. And with my luck, so far I only got gear with willpower.. well at least Jaesa is good equipped now :P.

Comment: I'm talking about the first time you get to Oricon(maybe you are talking about czerka). The first time you are on Oricon with a character you get for every quest a different peace of (66) gear. This gear is class specific. Oricon can be challenging for a new 55 so I suggest you go with a group or something.

Comment: The first item I got was a choice between Gear with Crit and Absorb. And I have no Problem questing there, I do it since 54.

Answer (score 0):

The game tests your knowledge of modding. Get defense mods and with basic gear you can start doing the hardmode flashpoints to get better gear with elite commendations and with gear rewards you can do the Tier 2 SM operations fine.